# Creating desktop shortcuts with "tasks" on right-click in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, shortcuts, desktop

I have noticed, that when I right click on, say, Firefox shortcut in Windows 10 taskbar, I have some extra options:

[image: firefox_shortcut_wind10_taskbar]

Namely, I have Open new tab, Open new Window, -- and New Private Window, which would correspond to the command line call `firefox -private-window`.

Note that I do **not** get these options, if I right-click the shortcut for the same Firefox on the desktop!

So my questions are:

- Can I have the extra options, also if right-clicking the Firefox shortcut on the Destop, not just the taskbar?
- What can I do, to have such extra options upon right click, for an arbitrary program? (say, as example, a batch file `myscript.bat` that accepts command line arguments, say `-day`, `-month`, `-year`; then I'd have a "Day" task which would call `myscript.bat -day`, and likewise for "Month" and "Year").

Answer (score 0):

If you extend the shortcut for firefox (this is done via the registry), it will extend EVERY shortcut as in add the "Day" task to the right click of "Notepad" and "Calc" as well.

You *could* (if you were a programmer) write a shell extension to filter for only Firefox and add anything you want to the right click.

Extending the task bar is done through different code than extending specific filetypes (in this case.. a shortcut).